# 5 columns in a wordpress loop wit 30 posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress, foreach

Is there any inbuilt css grid to implement a loop of 30 posts in five columns row?

If not, how can this be implemented safely to respond to all desktop and mobile devices?

Asking because I don't want to load any more plugins...

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code. Hopefully, work it.

```
<?php
    get_header();
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    if( have_posts() ):
        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
            <div class="col">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>        
        <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
<style>
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .col {
        flex: 1 0 18%; /* The important bit. This percentage decides your columns. 
        The percent can be px. It just represents your minimum starting width.
        */
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>


<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

Note: CSS move to your style.css. It's best practice.
Display result Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/6CyYWv1lkeKt